# Save ByteArray generated by Pixel Bender

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, mixing, pixel-bender

I am building a Flash Application which will allow a user to mix two mp3 files and send the mixed result to our server.

Using Pixel Bender I am already able to create a mix:

```
 public class Mixer
 { 
   [Embed(source="mix.pbj", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
protected var NewFilter:Class;
   private var shader:Shader;
   private var shaderJob:ShaderJob;
   protected var _output:ByteArray;
   shader = new Shader(new NewFilter() as ByteArray);

   private function onSampleDataHandler(event:SampleDataEvent):void 
   {
        var width:int = 1;
        var height:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>(numOfTracks);
        for (var i:int = 0; i < numOfTracks; i++)
        {
            buffer[i] = new ByteArray();
            sound[i].extract(buffer[i],BUFFER_SIZE * 4);
            height[i] = buffer[i].length >> 4;
            buffer[i].position = 0;
            shader.data["src"+i]["input"] = buffer[i];
            shader.data["src"+i]["width"] = width;
            shader.data["src"+i]["height"] = height[i];
        }

        shaderJob = new ShaderJob(shader, event.data,width, height[0]);
     shaderJob.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onShaderJobComplete, false, 0, true);
        shaderJob.start(false);
 }   

 protected function onShaderJobComplete(event:ShaderEvent):void
 {
        // event.byteArray is the result

 }
```

Not sure if the event.byteArray can be transformed to an mp3 file? Ideally we'd send the mp3 to our server for uploading.

Answer (score 0):

Shine MP3 is an open source mp3 encoder for Flash ported with Alchemy: http://code.google.com/p/flash-kikko/

Alternatively there is a WAV encoder in the sazameki audio manipulating library:
http://www.libspark.org/svn/as3/sazameki/trunk/src/org/sazameki/audio/format/Wav.as